# CloudFormation AWS::EC2::Route

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a Cloudformation template and I am confused with some concepts. First, do you need to drag and drop one Route object per every single route that you need to define inside a RouteTable?

Or can I just add more DestinationCidrBlock on the same Route?

```
AWS::EC2::Route
PrivateRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2PublicServer
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Don't put thanks into your question, do look at how it looks and make sure your code/data is readable (indent data wit 4 spaces, by selecting the block and clicking `{}`)

Comment: I pasted the code as it was generated by CloudFormation and It looked fine, I don't know what happened. Why not thanking in the post? It wasn't in the question, I thanked at the bottom of the paragraph.

Comment: Just pasting in code is not good enough, you have to format it ( you can see how it looked by clicking on the link "edited X hours ago". The tour clearly states "no distractions", so you should leave out anything from a question that doesn't make it more clear, i.e. anything unnecessary distracts  (greeting, thanks, advance appreciation, begging, etc.). Show your thanks by upvoting useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put multiple values in the **DestinationCidrBlock** property. It accepts only a String according to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-route.html#cfn-ec2-route-destinationcidrblock).

Unfortunately the AWS::EC2::RouteTable resource itself cannot include a list of routes. So you would need to add as many AWS::EC2::Route resources as routess you need to include.

Perhaps a possible solution would be to use a [CloudFormation transform Macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to generate multiple route resources from a list. I am not sure if this is possible.

---

Update:

I was able to do it using the [sample *Explode* macro](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Explode)

I wrote this template and it worked fine, creating a couple of routes pointing to the same Internet Gateway

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: Explode

Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: VPC ID of the VPC in which to create the route table

  InternetGateway:
    Type: String
    Description: Internet gateway id

Mappings:
  CidrMap:
    Destination1: 
      Cidr: 180.1.2.0/24
    Destination2:
      Cidr: 200.1.1.0/24

Resources:

  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId

  Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    ExplodeMap: CidrMap
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: "!Explode Cidr"
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
```